# Changing Sharepoint domain name

Tags: powershell, shell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am trying to change domain name in Sharepoint url from:

`microsofttempdomain.Sharepoint.com`  to  `my-newdomain.Sharepoint.com`

I have already connected this domain to Microsoft365 and created e-mail addresses. Domain which we have has dash "-" in it's name, I used this video guide  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/change-your-sharepoint-domain-name but when I try to change it using Sharepoint Online Management Shell on Windows 10 I get error:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Start-SPOTenantRename -DomainName my-newdomain -ScheduledDateTime "2022-05-31T12:00:00"
WARNING: Make sure you've carefully read about SPO Tenant Rename and understand its impact on your organization https://aka.ms/SPOTenantRename.


Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Start-SPOTenantRename."
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): y
CorrelationId: 586342a0-e0a3-4000-1bde-20e72a90ada3
Start-SPOTenantRename : Error Code: -758,The domain name isn't valid.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-SPOTenantRename -DomainName my-newdomain -ScheduledDateTime "2022- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-SPOTenantRename], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Error Code: -758,The domain name isn't valid.,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.Sta
   rtSPOTenantRename
```

It gives error 758 which means: `The domain name could either be null, empty; is longer than 48 characters; or contains a dash or special characters.` as I said before my domain contains dash.  When I remove dash it shows error 757 which means that `Domain name isn’t in the list of the verified domains for the tenant.`. So it means that it sees my domain as verified. Could you help me and tell me how can I change it? Is there some special symbols I need to add because of the dash in my domain name. Thank you!

SOLVED: If you want to change the sharedpoint name you need to add onmicrosoft.com domain with this name and than you will be able. I.E. if you want your sharedpoint to look like: mycompany321.sharedpoint.com, you have to add domain in Office365 as mycompany321.onmycrosoft.com

Comment: This might be a silly suggestion but have you tried wrapping the domain name in quotes `"`?

Comment: Hi, yes I did, but same issue. I also tried wrapping in backtick (it works in mysql command line) :(

Comment: I'm afraid you might need to rename your domain :(

Comment: I skipped that part from the guide since I already had a verified domain, but not an "onmicrosoft". Thanks!